# undefined method ` before_action' のエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## 前提・実現したいこと

Ruby on railsにてTwitterログインからの退会機能を作成しております。退会ボタンをおすと下記のメッセージが表示されてしまうのですが、対処方法をご教示頂けませんでしょうか？ 
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Routing Error 
undefined method ` before_action' for UsersController:Class

Rails.root: /Users/TOMOAKI/photolog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace app/controllers/users_controller.rb:2:in <class:UsersController>' 

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in <top (required)>' Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper    HTTP Verb    Path    Controller#Action Path / Url       Path Match

comments_path    GET    /comments(.:format)    comments#index 
                POST    /comments(.:format)    comments#create 
new_comment_path    GET    /comments/new(.:format)    comments#new 
edit_comment_path    GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit 
comment_path    GET    /comments/:id(.:format)    comments#show 
                PATCH    /comments/:id(.:format)    comments#update 
                PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)    comments#update 
                DELETE    /comments/:id(.:format)    comments#destroy 
new_user_session_path    GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new 
user_session_path    POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create 
destroy_user_session_path    DELETE    /users/sign_out(.:format)    devise/sessions#destroy 
user_omniauth_authorize_path    GET|
                POST    /users/auth/:provider(.:format)    users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/twitter|facebook/} 
user_omniauth_callback_path    GET|
                POST    /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)    users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:twitter|facebook) 
user_password_path    POST    /users/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#create 
new_user_password_path    GET    /users/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new 
edit_user_password_path    GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit 
                PATCH    /users/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#update 
                PUT    /users/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#update 
cancel_user_registration_path    GET    /users/cancel(.:format)    devise/registrations#cancel 
user_registration_path    POST    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#create 
new_user_registration_path    GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)    devise/registrations#new 
edit_user_registration_path    GET    /users/edit(.:format)    devise/registrations#edit 
                PATCH    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update 
                PUT    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update 
                DELETE    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#destroy 
root_path    GET    /    redirect(301, /photos) 
photos_path    GET    /photos(.:format)    photos#index 
                POST    /photos(.:format)    photos#create 
new_photo_path    GET    /photos/new(.:format)    photos#new 
edit_photo_path    GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format)    photos#edit 
photo_path    GET    /photos/:id(.:format)    photos#show 
                PATCH    /photos/:id(.:format)    photos#update 
                PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)    photos#update 
                DELETE    /photos/:id(.:format)    photos#destroy 
retire_user_path    GET    /user/retire(.:format)    users#retire 
user_path    POST    /user(.:format)    users#create 
new_user_path    GET    /user/new(.:format)    users#new 
edit_user_path    GET    /user/edit(.:format)    users#edit 
                GET    /user(.:format)    users#show 
                PATCH    /user(.:format)    users#update 
                PUT    /user(.:format)    users#update 
                DELETE    /user(.:format)    users#destroy
```

### Request

Parameters:

```
None Toggle session dump Toggle env dump Response
```

Headers:

```
None
```

## コード

app/users/users.contoller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate

  def retire
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user.destroy
      reset_session
      redirect_to root_path, notice:'退会完了しました'
    else
      render :retire
    end    
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
  root to: redirect('/photos')
  resources :photos
  resource :user do
    get 'retire'
  end

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
         has_many :photos, dependent: :nullify
         has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify


         def self.find_or_create_from_oauth(auth)
         User.find_or_create_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid) do |user|
         user.user_name  = auth.info.nickname || auth.info.name
         user.avatar_url = auth.info.image
         user.email      = User.dummy_email(auth)
         user.password   = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
    end
  end

  private

  def self.dummy_email(auth)
    "#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}@example.com"
  end

end
```

Comment: コードはそのまま貼り付けるのでは無く、行頭に空白4文字を入れてください。こうすると、コード用に書式が設定されてハイライトも適用されます。領域を選択して、上の「{}」アイコンをクリックすると自動的にやってくれます。

Comment: 使用している rails のバージョンを追記してください。もしかして `3.x` 系なのでは……

Answer (score 1):

before_actionというメソッド名のbの前に全角スペースが入っていて`空白before_action`というメソッド名になっているのでNoMethodErrorが発生します。
全角の文字は基本メソッド名に使えますので上記のようなエラーが出るかと思います。
Editorの設定で全角スペースは可視化するように設定を変更するとよいと思います。